# MySQL Polygon (Spatial) Insert Statement works sporadically

Tags: polygon, mysql-spatial

I know that MySQL doesn't have great spatial support at the moment, but is it *that* buggy that my insert statements would work sporadically? In general, longer coordinates seem to be failing on insert (there is no notice of them failing though, they just insert as NULL or show 0 rows affected on update). I believe though that I've seen large ones work and small ones fail. Here's my insert statement:

```
UPDATE places SET geom = PolygonFromText('POLYGON((-122.225255 37.890342,-122.22343 37.891445,-122.220923 37.89297...)),1') WHERE id=16
```

The only semi-logical things I can think of pertain to size/memory, or maybe invalid coordinates? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try optimising mysql config nnodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0 innodb_support_xa=0 innodb_buffer_pool_size=536870912 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837903/mysql-slow-insert

Comment: Can you provide an example that fails?

Comment: Here's a link to the statement: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s12/sh/b60b4124-1ba3-4940-afd4-cb8e80de1466/896df1339fa65a9a717578ff5fdc3404

Comment: FYI - Including @username at the start of a reply will notify a user that you've responded to their comment.

Answer (score 3):

By default, MySQL has a maximum packet size of 1 MB.  This can easily cause `INSERT` statements with complex polygons to fail.  You can check your maximum size in bytes using

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) explain a few different ways to adjust this parameter.

Comment: Good idea but didn't seem to fix it. Also I think if this was the case I would get an error, right now it's just null on insert or saying 0 rows affected for update

Answer (score 3):

From the example you linked, it looks you're giving MySQL a non-closed polygon. MySQL is happily accepting it and inserting `null` into the table instead.  Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE testing (geom geometry);
INSERT INTO testing (geom) VALUES 
    (PolygonFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0.00000003 0))'));
```

Running a `SELECT` on this table shows that the geometry field is `null`.  However, fixing the polygon results in a successful `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO testing (geom) VALUES 
    (PolygonFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))'));
```